# Custom Domain with Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, dns

I'm working on a research project and I currently own a domain (let's call it abc.xyz). I have purchased it on NameCheap and have some basic HTML/CSS/JavaScript running at the domain name (i.e. http://abc.xyz/index.html).

What I would like to do is use that same domain's sub-domains to be the FQDN for the Hadoop's domain, such that the **master** host would be **master.abc.xyz** and **slaveX** (where X is a number 1, 2, 3...) host would be **slaveX.abc.xyz**. What are the steps I must take to achieve this configuration? Will I have to give up hosting through NameCheap's cPanel?

Comment: do you have seperate IP addresses for all your hadoop instances? and do you need/want reverse dns as well?

Comment: They all have separate IP addresses, yes. I don't know what you mean by the reverse dns requirements.

Comment: change the `hostname` in each instances according to your needs and also modify the `/etc/hosts` to map ip addresses to the updated hostname. That should solve I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the control panel for your domain host you should find the option to add either `A` and or `CNAME` records to your existing domain `abc.xyz`.

As you have indicated you have IP addresses for each Hadoop instance then you could add `A` records along these lines;

```
master A <IP of master instance>
slave1 A <IP of slave 1>
slave2 A <IP of slave 2>
```

You also have the option of using `CNAME` records which are simply and alias for the existing domain name your Hadoop instances have.

```
master CNAME <fqdn of instance>
slave1 CNAME <fqdn of instance>
slave2 CNAME <fqdn of instance>
```

Once you have made your changes remember to increment your zone serial number (presuming the control panel doesn't do it for you.) wait a short time then your changes should propagate and allow you to access your instances via your own domain name.

If you need further help please post a comment & I can update my answer for you.